# How to pass an array through a prototype?

Tags: javascript

Whenever I try to pass an `array` through a `prototype`, I always get an `error`.
I want to start passing an `array` into `prototypes`. But, I do not know how.

The results for the demo should `log` `false`

```js
String.prototype.isGreaterThan = function(n) {
  return this.length > n
}


myArray = ["one", "two", "three"]
a = myArray.isGreaterThan(5)




console.log(a)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myArray` is an array but not string whereas the prototype method is added to String data type instead of Array.Change it to `Array.prototype.isGreaterThan`

```js
Array.prototype.isGreaterThan = function(n) {
  return this.length > n
}

let myArray = ["one", "two", "three"]
a = myArray.isGreaterThan(5)
console.log(a)
```